# How can I achieve a high decoration rating with Paddleboats?

Tags: parkitect

My understanding is that the decoration rating of a ride can increase its excitement rating, and a higher excitement rating allows you to charge more for a ride. So for low excitement rides like the paddleboat, decorations seem to be really important. However, I'm having trouble getting the decoration rating for [Paddleboats](https://parkitect.fandom.com/wiki/Paddleboats) above "Bad", which is the lowest rating possible (I think).

Pictured below is an example of a paddleboat ride I've installed in Batavia Cay. As you can see, I've set up multiple decorations in the water area accessible to the paddleboats, as well as a few trees next to the ride queue. Despite this, however, I still have a decoration rating of "Bad".

[image: paddleboats parkitect]

How can I achieve higher level decoration ratings for Paddleboat rides?